# Is it safe to use double bang (!!) with a RegEx match?

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have the following code:

```js
const isArrayField = type => !!type.match(/^Array\[\w+\]$/);

const type = 'Array[IncidentRole]';

console.log(isArrayField(type));
```

All I need to know is if the string matched the regex. I don’t need the matches. In this case, is it safe to use !! to force `isArrayField` to return a boolean? If not, why?

Comment: Better to use `regex.test(str)` for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's safe, yes. If it matches, `match` will return an array, and `!anyArray` is `false`, so `!!anyArray` is `true`. If it doesn't match, `match` returns `null`, and `!null` is `true` so `!!null` is `false`. There aren't any lurking TypeErrors waiting to happen or similar. :-)

But there's a better answer: The [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) function on the regex, which returns a boolean:

```js
const isArrayField = type => /^Array\[\w+\]$/.test(type);
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

const type = 'Array[IncidentRole]';

console.log(isArrayField(type));
```

Comment: Fabulous. I don’t know how `test` slipped my mind. Thanks so much!